# Stuck in loop while trying to get input from cin

Tags: c++, iostream

Okay I'm very new to C++, I'm experianced with C# and I don't really know what is wrong in my code. I'm just trying to figure out how to check whether the user's input is a integer or string.

But when I type 'a' or some other string, the while loop never ends.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    int number;
    goto skip;
    do
    {
        cout << "Wrong input. Try again.";
skip:
        cout << "Number: ";
        cin >> number;
    }
    while (!cin);
    cout << "Correct input.";
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once your stream has gone into failure mode it will stay in failure mode until you `clear()` its state bits. However, merely clearing the bits won't help because the offending character will stay in the stream. Most likely you want to ignore the entire line before retrying:

```
while (!(std::cout << "Number: " && std::cin >> number)) {
    std::cout << "Wrong input. Try again.\n";
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
std::cout << "Correct input.\n";
std::cin.ignore();
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Unfortunately, I have to look for each line because I havent understood most of it.