# Catching the invalid input when cin fails

Tags: c++

I'm prompting the user to enter a number between 1 and 13. When the user inputs invalid data, I not only need to inform him it is incorrect and prompt him again, but check if the invalid data is a 'Q' or 'q'. In the last case I will quit the program.

The only issue is that when using cin to get data I can't interact with it. What I'd like to do is when cin fails to store the string and check if it is a Q or q. How could I do this?

Edit:
In case I didn't articulate properly, all I would like to do is check the contents of the input when it fails.

```
int input;
cin >> input;
if(cin.fail()){
    if(???){
    // Check if input == 'q' || input == 'Q'
    // Quit if thats the case
    }

    // Otherwise inform the user its invalid input
    else{
        cout << "Invalid input" << endl;
        cin << input;
    }
```

}

Edit: This isn't a duplicate of how to clear and ignore input. I know how to do that. I need to interact with the invalid input and check if it is a Q or not.

Comment: It's hard to tell you what's wrong with code we can't see.

Comment: "*The only issue is that when using cin to get data I can't interact with it.*" -- Please show what you have done and what you mean by "can't interact with it".

Comment: You have to check the data for two things. Which means you need to store a copy of it. All data from a stream is in bytes, which are stored into strings. So you need to first read your data into a ____. Then you check if it contains ____. If not you try to convert your ____ into ____.

Comment: Muadh, cin >> ?? is assigned to what? Use an if statement on "that" variable, and watch out for string/int

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stuck in loop while trying to get input from cin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19128005/stuck-in-loop-while-trying-to-get-input-from-cin)

Comment: @kfsone I know how to clear and ignore, the only issue is that I want to interact with the invalid input. If I output input when it isn't an integer its a weird character, not a value I can check if is Q or not

Comment: If you know all that, then you know that cin didn't consume the characters.

Comment: It does. If I ask for an int input, and get a character, I can't directly compare it to a string or char. I don't remember C++ syntax very well; I know there is a way to do it but I dont remember

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to call `cin.clear` to clear the error condition--until you do that, all attempts at reading from it will fail. After that, you can read a character and check if it's one you care about, something on this general order:

```
cin.clear();
char ch;
cin >> ch;
if (ch == 'q' || ch == 'Q')
    quit();
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!